i trying to make a test on my flutter project
i trying to make a test on flutter with my tdd project but i got these error
Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method?
here my repo

abstract class HomeRepository {

    Future<Either<Failure,BaseModel>> testCase({required ApiRequest apiRequest});
}

here my usecase
class TestCase {
  HomeRepository homeRepository;
  TestCase({required this.homeRepository});
  Future<Either<Failure,BaseModel>>call({required ApiRequest apiRequest})async{
    return await homeRepository.testCase(apiRequest: apiRequest);
  }
}

### now here is my test page
class HomeTest extends Mock implements HomeRepository{
  @override
  Future<Either<Failure,BaseModel>> testCase({required ApiRequest apiRequest})async{
     return await Right(AppModel.otpVerify);
  }

}


void main(){
  ApiRequest apiRequest = ApiRequest(method: ApiMethod.post, endPoint: '/');
  late HomeTest homeTest;
  late TestCase testCase;
    setUp(() {
      homeTest = HomeTest();
      testCase = TestCase(homeRepository: homeTest);

    });


  test('testcase', () async {
    // Setup
    when(homeTest.testCase(apiRequest: apiRequest)).thenAnswer((_) async => right(AppModel.otpVerify));

    // Action
    final result = await testCase(apiRequest: apiRequest);

    // Verification
    expect(result, right(AppModel.otpVerify)); // Ensure the expected result matches the actual result
  });

}

im trying to run test correctly

i find a the soultion :)
just replace this import
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

to this
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

**so the testing i correct some error this is new one **
class MockAuthRepo extends Mock implements AuthRepositories {

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, BaseModel>> testCase({required ApiRequest apiRequest}) async {
    return await Future.value(right(AppModel.otpVerify));
  }
}

void main() {
  late MockAuthRepo mockAuthRepo;
 late PhoneVerifyUseCase useCase;
  OtpPageModel otpPageModel = OtpPageModel(phoneNumber: '0939048067');
  ApiRequest apiRequest = ApiRequest(
    method: ApiMethod.post,
    endPoint: EndPoints.login,
    model: AppModel.loginModel,
    body: otpPageModel.toJson(),
  );
  setUp(() {
    mockAuthRepo = MockAuthRepo();
    useCase= PhoneVerifyUseCase(authRepositories: mockAuthRepo);

  });

  test('should get trivia for the number from the repository', () async{
    // Setup
    when(() => mockAuthRepo.phoneVerify(apiRequest: apiRequest))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => right(AppModel.loginModel));

    // Action
    final result = await useCase(apiRequest: apiRequest);

    // Verification
    expect(result, Right(AppModel.loginModel));

  });

}

and the repo is
abstract class AuthRepositories{

   Future<Either<Failure,BaseModel>> phoneVerify({required ApiRequest apiRequest});
   Future<Either<Failure,BaseModel>> otpVerify({required ApiRequest apiRequest});
   Future<Either<Failure,BaseModel>> getAppOptions({required ApiRequest apiRequest});

}

and the use case is
`
class PhoneVerifyUseCase{
AuthRepositories authRepositories ;
PhoneVerifyUseCase({required this.authRepositories});

Future<Either<Failure,BaseModel>>call({required ApiRequest apiRequest})async{
return await authRepositories.phoneVerify(apiRequest: apiRequest);
}

}`

